# import CSV as database Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, django-models, frameworks

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file. I'm using this code:

```
from django.db import models
import csv

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField()  # field - instance - row
    description = models.TextField(max_length=700)  # field - instance - row
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # field - instance - row
    celltype = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # field - instance - row
    component = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # field - instance - row
    doi = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # field - instance - row
    organism = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # field - instance - row
    def deleteAll(self):
        for img in self.objects.all():
            img.delete()

    def ImportData(self):
        path = '/Users/macbookair/Downloads/source_project/images.csv'
        reader = csv.reader(open(path), delimiter=";", quotechar='"')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            image = Image()
            image.name = row[1]
            image.description = row[2]
            image.mode = row[3]
            image.celltype = row[4]
            image.component = row[5]
            image.doi = row[6]
            image.organism = row[7]
            image.save()
```

my CSV file looks like this:
[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Snc.png)

But when I go to console to check my Image model, I find that it is empty!
I'm checking this way:
in console:

```
python manage.py shell


from myApp.models import Image


image.objects.all()
```

and I get:
<QuerySet []>

I already made the migrations using:
python manage.py makemigrations myApp
python manage.py migrate

am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you *call* teh `ImportData` method? Django will not "automatically" process each method you define.

Comment: Consider using `django-import-export` (https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It makes life easier.